# Firebase Admin Node.js Read/Write Database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, admin

It seems I can't find a proper way to use the `read/write` functions for admin in the Cloud Functions. I am working on a messaging function that reads new messages created in the Realtime Database with Cloud Functions Node.js and uses the snapshot to reference a path. Here is my initial exports function:

```
var messageRef = functions.database.ref('Messages/{chatPushKey}/Messages/{pushKey}');

var messageText;

exports.newMessageCreated = messageRef.onCreate((dataSnapshot, context) => {
    console.log("Exports function executed");

    messageText = dataSnapshot.val().messageContent;
    var chatRef = dataSnapshot.key;
    var messengerUID = dataSnapshot.val().messengerUID;

    return readChatRef(messengerUID, chatRef);

});
```

And here is the function that reads from the value returned:

```
function readChatRef(someUID, chatKey){
  console.log("Step 2");

  admin.database.enableLogging(true);

  var db;
  db = admin.database();

  var userInfoRef = db.ref('Users/' + someUID + '/User Info');

  return userInfoRef.on('value', function(snap){
     return console.log(snap.val().firstName);
  });

}
```

In the firebase cloud functions log I can read all console.logs except for the one inside `return userInfoRef.on...`. Is my syntax incorrect? I have attempted several other variations for reading the snap. Perhaps I am not using callbacks efficiently? I know for a fact that my service account key and admin features are up to date.

If there is another direction I need to be focusing on please let me know.

Comment: You should use once() instead of on() in Cloud Functions.

Comment: Your `readChatRef` function may just return a promise and the firebase function terminates before it has resolved. Try using an async function if you're working in node 8 `const readChatRef = async (someUID, chatKey) => {`